# virtualhosts not seen in apache 2.4 conf

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4

i'm running Apache 2.4 on Fedora linux and at the moment i got a problem with virtualhosts..

I think that 2.4 requires a different  configuration than the other one (2.2) i was more used to but i'm not sure about this. However the problem is the following, i have a working documentroot but i got two project in my documentroot i would like to run separately on different virtual so i added those lines to the httpd.conf file in conf directory in etc:

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
        ServerAdmin me@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot "/home/me/workspace/project1/"
        ServerName localhost/project1
        ErrorLog "logs/project1.error.log"
        CustomLog "logs/project1.access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost localhost:80>
        ServerAdmin me@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot "/home/me/workspace/project2/"
        ServerName localhost/project2
        ErrorLog "logs/project2.error.log"
        CustomLog "logs/project2.access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm not sure why, however the server is runnign from the documentroot and when i type for instance: localhost/project2 it gives me a not found error (404)..
The error log is silent while the access log only reports a 404..

I'm probably missing something crucial. Can someone help?

thanks in advance

Comment: That config wouldn't have worked in Apache 2.2, either.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a correct servername:

```
ServerName localhost/project1
```

ServerName has to be an IP or a domain name, not a path

You can do this :

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
        ServerAdmin me@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot "/home/me/workspace/"
        ServerName localhost
        ErrorLog "logs/project1.error.log"
        CustomLog "logs/project1.access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Like that you will have `http://yourip/project1/` & `http://yourip/project2/`. Then add an index file to `/workspace` to redirect wherever you want

Now, if you want to do thing well, you can use 2 IP for your server and access each project with different IP:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin me@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot "/home/me/workspace/project1/"
        ServerName 192.168.0.101
        ErrorLog "logs/project1.error.log"
        CustomLog "logs/project1.access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin me@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot "/home/me/workspace/project2/"
        ServerName 192.168.0.102
        ErrorLog "logs/project2.error.log"
        CustomLog "logs/project2.access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

If you can use DNS you can replace IP By DNS name (even in with local DNS)